# How can I get the length of a video in node.js

Tags: node.js, video

My backend needs to check to see if a video is under 60 seconds, or else it doesn't add the link to the database. Is there any easy solution if I have the file on disk? Something simple like videofile.getDuration()

I checked out FFMEG on npm but I'm not sure if that's what I need or if that's even up to date.

Comment: There's the aptly named [get-video-duration](https://www.npmjs.com/package/get-video-duration) middleware

Comment: says the dependencies are out of date..?

Answer (score 1):

I use [ffprobe](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ffprobe) for the task.

If you follow the `README` and you get to read the streams' info you will be able to get the duration by accessing the following tag on the video stream:

```
info.streams[0].tags.DURATION
```

There might be variants according to the kind of video file you are parsing, this example works with `mkv`.